# Functions "_IEFormElementSetValue" and "_IEAction" in AutoIT

Tags: autoit

Why can I not run these features one after another? Functions `_IEFormElementSetValue()` and `_IEAction()` do not work together?

*Code:*

```cpp
#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.google.com")
WinSetState("[ACTIVE]", "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)

; Feature 1: inserts the text into the search box google
Local $oDigita = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "q")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oDigita, "Nome pesquisado")

; Feature 2: option button "I'm feeling lucky"
Local $oClica = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "btnI")
_IEAction($oClica, "click")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on AutoIt version *3.3.14.2*, IE version *11.0.9600.19266*. Try my adjusted variant below, because the behavior of `_IECreate()` isn't always stable.

**Code:**

```
#include-once
#include <IE.au3>

Global $oIE = _IECreate( 'http://www.google.com', 0, 1, 1, 1 )
WinSetState( '[ACTIVE]', '', @SW_MAXIMIZE )
Sleep( 1000 )

; Feature 1: inserts the text into the search box google
Global $oDigita = _IEGetObjByName( $oIE, 'q' )
_IEAction( $oDigita, 'click' )

ClipPut( 'Nome pesquisado' ) ; save string in clipboard
Send( '^v' )                 ; paste string with CTRL+V

; Feature 2: option button "I'm feeling lucky"
Global $oClica = _IEGetObjByName( $oIE, 'btnI' )
_IEAction( $oClica, 'click' )
```

**Notice:**

The function `_IEAction()` is quite unstable just like `Send()`. I suggest to use an IE object, embedded into a GUI with `_IECreateEmbedded()` instead.